# I'm using trumbowyg as text editor for the textareas in my forum, but how do I echo it?

Tags: php, html, echo, wysiwyg, trumbowyg

I didn't find any post related to my problem, so here I go :

I added **trumbowyg** (it's a WYSIWYG editor) to edit the content in my `<textarea></textarea>`, and it works just fine when I post it in my database.

Only problem is : how do I *echo* it ?

The parsing method of **trumbowyg** takes this form : you click on, let's say **B** in the toolbar on top of the textarea, and it will put your text in bold weight. But in the server, once posted, it takes actually this form : `<strong>some text</strong>`.

Obviously, when I echo the var stocking the data in this part of my sql request, it output it the same way : `<strong>some text</strong>` and not **some text**.

I don't know if it's actually so simple that I can't seem to find the solution, or if I'm trying something impossible... ?

Thanks by advance guys !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... Guess it was so obvious that I didn't find the answer in here. If it can help people who find themselves in the same situation as me : just wrap your var containing html with `html_entity_decode($var)`
That's it.

See below (textarea is showed if the user consulting the profile is the one wich it belongs to, else it just echo the descrption (called in an Action.php file, I didn't put the "requires" before the `<!DOCTYPE html>` declaration.

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<?php include "includes/head.php"; ?>
<body>
    <?php include ("includes/navbar.php") ?>
    <div class="container">
    <h2><?= $user_pseudo;?></h2>
    <h5><?= $user_access_level;?></h5>
    <?php
      if($_SESSION['id'] == $user_id){
    ?>
    <form method="POST">
        <textarea id="parse" name="description"><?= $user_description; ?></textarea>
        
        <button class="btn btn-primary" name="validate" type="submit">Mettre à jour</button>
    </form>


    <?php
      } else {
    ?>
    <br/><br/><br/>
    <div class="container">
        <?= html_entity_decode($user_description) ?>
    </div>
    </div>
<?php
  }
?>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
        <script src="trumbowyg/dist/trumbowyg.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $('#parse').trumbowyg();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please write a snippet for the code you're describing? Thanks

Comment: I added this, is this enough ? :)

Comment: looks good. thanks